# Display time range formatted with PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

I'm using [PHPSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to generate an XLS file with report data, and in some situations, display an XLS formatted as HTML on screen.

How can I display a formatted time range in an Excel worksheet?

I have a range of `25:30` hours that I would like to show using HH:MM:SS format, but if I use the code below it shows as `01:30:00`.

```
$seconds = 91800;
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit('L' . $row, (seconds / 86400) , PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('L'.$row)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('HH:MM:SS');
```

If I change the time format to `[HH]:MM:SS`, the HTML displays a buggy result:

```
<span style="color:hh">[01]:30:00</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes time ranges are a bit tricky. The easyer way is:

You can make a Time string with plane php and use a text column to store the data.